# How to store multiple variables returned from a SELECT in arrays of their own - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm rewriting all my old mysql code as PDO code but I can't think of a way to store multiple variables returned from a SELECT in arrays of their own.

I can put ONE set of values in a new array as follows:

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT P_ID 
    FROM personal 
    WHERE personal.firstname=:firstname
    AND personal.lastname=:lastname");

// Bind 
// Execute
// Fetch 

// Store
    if ($row) 
      {
            foreach ($row as $key) 
            {
              $PIDs[] = $key;
            }
      }
```

But in this query I want to put firstnames **and** secondnames in **different** arrays:

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM personal");
```

In mysql I was doing:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
     {
        $firstnames[] = $row[0];
        $lastnames[] = $row[1];
     }
```

Can someone please help? Every sample PDO SELECT I can find only handles one returned field.

Comment: You have errors? .. wrong result? ... show a proper data sample, your actual result and the expected  result

Comment: Why do you think you need any different approach with PDO? It's a second time you are asking a question which is irrelevant to PDO

Comment: I'm still getting the hang of it. Rome wasn't built in a day.

Comment: You better get hang of your old mysql code. Apparently you have no idea how it worked as well

Comment: Are you a happy person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) data from your statement `$stmt`:

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM personal");
$stmt2->execute();

while ($row = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    $firstnames[] = $row['FirstName'];
    $lastnames[] = $row['LastName'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the `PDO fetch mode` so you can reference the 2D array by name and then fetch all of the rows.

```
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

More information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.setfetchmode.php).

And then you can use `array_column`, more information can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php);

```
$firstNames = array_column($result, 'FirstName');
$lastNames = array_column($result, 'LastName');
```